# Email sent from SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow not received

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, email

After migration my SharePoint 2010 web application to 2013, I created a sample workflow in SP Designer 2013 by selecting SP 2010 platform for sending email alert whenever a new item is added in a SharePoint list.

After adding a new item in a list the workflow started and completed successfully but I didn't get the email, all remaining actions worked perfectly. I didn't see any error message in the workflow History List.

I logged the Email Id to the workflow history list using "current Item CreatedBy". It is getting the email id of current user and storing it in the Workflow History list without any issues.

I provided the SMTP mail server in Central Administration->Outgoing Email Settings and also provided in IIS - Default Website(80).

I installed SMTP server in Windows Server 2008 R2 using "Add Features".

But I didn't get email from my workflow. Are any additional configuration steps required?

Comment: You can check if any alerts on the list are working? This will check if the configuration is coorect.

Comment: Try http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx

Comment: I checked alerts on the list. But mails not received. I will troubleshoot by using the given link

Comment: Yo the problem is not with Workflows, please check the link i have given

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that, Alerts even not working on the list. So, Most probably the issue is with your SMTP configuration rather your workflow.

I would recommend follow the instruction below technet and make sure you followed everything.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288949(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288949%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Networking/Protocols/Email/Q_28170459.html